# Objects.requireNonNull error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, crash, android-actionbar, require

The line of code crashes my app :-

`Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();`

I don't know why, can anyone help me...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSupportActionBar()` returns null. And since you require it to be non-null, it crashes.